# What is the most efficient way to access resources?

Tags: c++, resource-management

I have a resource manager that loads and returns resources. Currently, I just return `shared_ptrs` for the resources I create, but I'm thinking about going over to using something like simple handles, whereby you get an ID you use to access the resource. The reasons are more explicit ownership, and also less overhead, rather than using `smart_ptrs`.

Are resource handles the most efficient way to access resources, should I stick with shared_ptrs or are there other alternatives?

The reason I am asking is that I was reading this [article](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/a-simple-fast-resource-manager-using-c-and-stl-r2503), which made me wonder if I should implement something like that, instead.

Comment: I would definitely say that integer based handles are the way to go. If you want it to be more flashy/intuitive, you could also just use enums. This way you could better enumerate the various assets.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with Vittorio about not needing shared ownership of resources and, while I dislike the implementation of `shared_ptr`, it can be made to work just fine.

You want shared ownership because, of course, multiple game objects might be using the same resource.  More importantly, if you have multiple levels and want to minimum level loading, you need some way to compute the union and intersection of resources needed by both.

One way to do this, which does require something more than just a `shared_ptr`, is to allow "loading" a level without resources and letting it take shared ownership of resources it needs.  Then unload the old level, removing its ownership.  Then, for any resource that still has ownership active but isn't loaded, load the resource.

For a resource A needed by levels 1 and 2, the reference count goes something like:

```
load level 1
ref=1
load A
load level 2
ref=2
unload level 1
ref=1
```

For a resource B used by only level 1, it goes like:

```
load level 1
ref=1
load B
load level 2
ref=1
unload level 1
ref=0 (removed)
```

And a resource C used by only level 2, it goes like:

```
load level 1
ref=0 (implicit, as no resource C exists)
load level 2
ref=1
unload level 1
load C
```

One method might be to have a layer of indirection.  You store `shared_ptr` to a `ResourceHolder`.  These holders are also in a list of some kind.  When loading a level, you create and hold on to these `ResourceHolder` objects.  They contain a `unique_ptr` to the actual resource (initially `nullptr`) and the path or other information needed to eventually load the item.

After loading the new level and unloading the old, you can then iterate through the list of live `ResourceHolder` objects, find any that have a `nullptr` handle to the actual resource, and then load it.  When the `shared_ptr` to a `ResourceHolder` hits a ref count of 0 and unloads it, it also naturally frees the resource, and you should ensure that it removes itself from the list of live resources.

You can do much better than `shared_ptr` but it's a perfectly fine place to start to get up and running.  Optimize it into something better later on once you have a working game.

Comment: What are the benefits of shared resource ownership? Even if many objects require the same resource, they can simply store a reference or non-owning pointer to it.

Comment: I explained it in this post with reference count sequence examples.  If you don't have shared ownership, you don't know when to unload or reload resources when you transition levels, unless you make the levels themselves owners (which is crappy, because I don't want to have to manually tag which resources each levels needs; I just want to add objects to a level resource and have it all work automatically).

Comment: Your use case is really interesting and maybe a very reasonable case for genuine shared ownership. I've often developed a phobia of `shared_ptr` and even GC in general though from past experiences working in teams, where both of these were thought to be excuses to avoid thinking about resource management and ownership at all.. and the result was a lot of logical leaks, where the analogical dangling pointer crash turned into a silent memory leak that flew under the radar of testing, since a resource would store a shared_ptr to another whose lifetime should have been terminated long [...]

Comment: [...] before the outer resource storing that `shared_ptr`. I have become reluctant of shared_ptrs and even GC ever since with all the hard-to-spot leaks I encountered.

Comment: In our case it was like the renderer might store a matte exclusion list of strong mesh references to exclude from rendering, a light might store a light exclusion list of strong refs, a shader plugin might share ownership for a texture it uses as input, etc. etc. etc. Everything ends up kinda sharing in the ownership of all kinds of other things, and often a bulky resource like a mesh might be shared in ownership by 20 places in the system... and 19 of those places might null out the reference or remove it from a list in response to the proper event, but one would fail...

Comment: ... and then instead of a dangling pointer crash, we'd get this huge memory leak that was really hard to trace down while all of our unit and integration tests were passing. I think with care and a good team with good standards, `shared_ptr` and garbage collection might be quite useful.. but I've got a phobia of both just from that leak perspective.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the most efficient way to access resources. The same Sean Middleditch who gave you an answer wrote an article "[Dangers of std::shared_ptr](http://seanmiddleditch.com/dangers-of-stdshared_ptr/)" against using `shared_ptr` about one year later. You might consider using handles again. As he wrote himself:

> Game engines have long supported this kind of borrowed reference using things like unique ID handles. Instead of storing a pointer (smart or otherwise) to an object, store a numeric ID instead (possibly wrapped in a templated type to ensure type safety).

Please review the section **Efficiency** in his article for more explanations on how to be much more efficient when using handles in contrast to `shared_ptr`.

For more advantages of IDs you can read the short **Entity Component System Pattern** [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system#Design_of_an_entity).